# Doubt in Python FOR cycle

Tags: python

I'm with some doubts in a Python FOR cycle:

This code works great:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = range(8)

_ = float('inf')

   # a b c d e f g h
W = [
    [0,2,1,3,9,4,_,_], # a
    [_,0,4,_,3,_,_,_], # b
    [_,_,0,8,_,_,_,_], # c
    [_,_,_,0,7,_,_,_], # d
    [_,_,_,_,0,5,_,_], # e
    [_,_,2,_,_,0,2,2], # f
    [_,_,_,_,_,1,0,6], # g
    [_,_,_,_,_,9,8,0]] # h

sum(1 for w in W[a] if w < _) - 1 # Degree
```

My question is:

The the "FOR x IN y IF x < 10" only works inside a SUM?

I have tested this but it does not work:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = range(8)

_ = float('inf')

   # a b c d e f g h
W = [
    [0,2,1,3,9,4,_,_], # a
    [_,0,4,_,3,_,_,_], # b
    [_,_,0,8,_,_,_,_], # c
    [_,_,_,0,7,_,_,_], # d
    [_,_,_,_,0,5,_,_], # e
    [_,_,2,_,_,0,2,2], # f
    [_,_,_,_,_,1,0,6], # g
    [_,_,_,_,_,9,8,0]] # h

for w in W[a] if w < _:
    print 1
```

Best Regards,

Comment: What tutorial are you reading?  Please find the section on "list comprehension".  Please **update** your question to provide a link to your tutorial.  If you do that, then we can show you where in that tutorial the section on list comprehensions is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
for k in [w for w in W[a] if w < _]:
    print 1
```

You need to use the `if` clause within a list comprehension (but as noted in the comment, this is not the optimal way to do this).

**Edit:** If you are looking to learn some of the 'awesome' features of python, you could also try using `itertools`:

```
for k in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x < _ ,W[0]):
    print 1
```

There are many other solutions, some more or less elegant and efficient than others. If you want to get really awesome and you are basically using array structures, look into `numpy` to unlock a whole world of elegance and speed.

Comment: Wasteful. This makes a whole list before it even starts iterating. Use generator expressions (depressing that so many people don't know or ignore some of the most awesome language features), or the more common way to write filtering list comprehensions by hand: `for k in W[a]: if w < _: print 1`.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the if clause in the for statement is only allowed in list comprehension or generator expression. See http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

Comment: There is no `if` clause in the `for` **statement**. There is an `if` clause in list comprehensions and generator expressions, both of which resemble (but are not!) a for statement.